# Make larger capacitance using multiple capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, parallel, capacitance, series

Can I connect five 100μF capacitors in series or parallel to form 500μF in total that I can use like a regular 500μF capacitor? (Apologies for noob question.)

Comment: You can connect five 100uF capacitors in series to make ... 20 uF.

Comment: Capacitors add in parallel, resistors add in series, inductors add in series. I think the Wikipedia article on capacitors would have been a good read and avoided an unnecessary question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The formula for capacitors in parallel is

$$ C_{Total} = C_1+C_2 + C_3 + ... $$

Make sure that each one is rated for at least the voltage you will apply to them.

For reference, capacitors in series are calculated as follows:

$$ \frac {1}{C_{Total}} = \frac {1}{C_1} + \frac {1}{C_2} + \frac {1}{C_3} + ... $$

Comment: Yep. Notice capacitors add the opposite way of resistors.

Comment: @Jim: Probably the opposite way to inductors as they are usually complimentary to capacitors. We think it's opposite to resistors because we measure their _resistance_ (ohms) but if we measured their _conductance_ (siemens) we would add them directly to calculate the parallel conductance - just like the capacitors. (You're not wrong, by the way.)

Comment: Agreed, good point for the OP, that inductors and caps are generally considered complimentary. As the OP is new to EE.SE and it seems electronics in general, I was assuming he had some resistor experience he could use as a baseline. Regardless, you answered his question.

Comment: @Jim *complementary*, though they are usually polite if they know what's good for them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use 5x 100uF capacitors in parallel to get 500uF capacitance. It is like 1x 500uF capacitor.
But there is some advantage. Capacitors with lower capacity usually have lower ESR. So when you use 5 smaller caps instead of 1 bigger one you will get better performance in this respect. This is common practice.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand, the 5 smaller caps will collectively take up more pc board space than 1 big one. It's a tradeoff (as is so often the case).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on application, you must look up specs of original cap for ESR.

"Low ESR" rated caps have a charge time constant on the order of 1-10us and "general purpose" (G.P.) caps are typically> 100 us to > 1ms.

This time constant is related to dissipation factor and heat rise and max current ripple rating for the cap.

The results depend again on the application for low ripple voltage Ipp*ESR can be significant.

In the same family of caps at the same V rating, you will find 1x500uF and 5x100uF or 10x50uF to have similar C* ESR constant values.

But between brands and quality factors which affect cost for low ESR caps, 1x500uF original low ESR cap will be better than 5x 100uF G.P. caps.

Read the datasheets of recommended part or original part for ESR if given and report below.